# Add actions to remote notifications in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure Notification Hub to send and receive remote notifications in my Xamarin.iOS app and it is working just fine. However, what I would like to implement is that when user slides or touches the notification, the app needs to perform certain actions, e.g. opening the page relevant to the notification.

How can I implement this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft docs cover how to add actions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=vsmac#creating-custom-actions

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Create action
var actionID = "reply";
var title = "Reply";
var action = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier (actionID, title, UNNotificationActionOptions.None);

// Create category
var categoryID = "message";
var actions = new UNNotificationAction [] { action };
var intentIDs = new string [] { };
var categoryOptions = new UNNotificationCategoryOptions [] { };
var category = UNNotificationCategory.FromIdentifier (categoryID, actions, intentIDs, UNNotificationCategoryOptions.None);

// Register category
var categories = new UNNotificationCategory [] { category };
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.SetNotificationCategories (new NSSet<UNNotificationCategory>(categories));
```

This is simple enough. But you'll need to send your action information through the notification payload.

You can define your JSON payload however you wish. For a recent app, I did something like this:

```
{"aps":{"alert":$"{message}", "action": "0", "actionText" : $"{text}"}}
```

Then when you receive the payload, you'll need to extract the value and act on it.

```
void ProcessNotification(NSDictionary options, bool fromFinishedLaunching)
{                      
    // Check to see if the dictionary has the aps key.  This is the notification payload you would have sent
    if (null != options && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
    {
        //Get the aps dictionary
        var aps = options.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary; 

        string 
            alert = string.Empty, 
            actionText = string.Empty, 
            action = string.Empty; 

        if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
            alert = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();

        if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("action")))
            action = (aps[new NSString("action")] as NSString).ToString();

        if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("actionText")))
            actionText = (aps[new NSString("actionText")] as NSString).ToString();

        // now that you have your payload extracted you can create your notification 

    }
}
```

In my situation I was working with Xamarin Forms, so I used ReactiveUI's MessageBus and passed a notification up to the Forms application to open up the correct page for the notification.

Let me know if you need any more details.